# HIghland.js: What's the difference between fork() and observe()?

Tags: javascript, stream, fork, highland.js

I understand that `observe()` doesn't consume values or trigger consumption unless some other consumer is already at work, whereas `fork()` triggers consumption by itself. However, suppose I have a stream `source_stream`. If I do

```
var observer_1 = source_stream .observe ();
var observer_2 = source_stream .observe ();
source_stream .each ( console .log );
```

Then the two observers are guaranteed to receive the same values. But if I do

```
var forker_1 = source_stream .fork ();
var forker_2 = source_stream .fork ();
```

What values would go into the two forkers? Would they be the same, different, or something else? What rule determines what values get pushed into them? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I did solve this, but I don't recall my solution. I've switch thereafter to most.js and flyd. flyd looks better and is more functional but has rough edges. Good luck!